# Error with registration token in FCM with Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have deployed the following JavaScript to Firebase Cloud Function but I am constantly getting the following error even though I know that there is a token saved under the path specified.

The idea is to trigger a notification to device when a new message is written to the database, it then fetches the registration token which is then used to try and send a notification to the user.

[image]

> Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.

JS Function:

```
exports.notifyNewMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/{message}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const message = snap.val();
  const fromId = message['fromId'];
  const toId = message['toId'];
  const messageTxt = message ['message'];
  const imageUrl = message ['imageUrl'];


  return admin.database().ref('/fcmtokens/' + toId + '/registration-tokens').once('value').then((userTok) => {

    const registrationTokens = userTok.val()

    console.log(registrationTokens);

    return admin.database().ref('/users' + fromId).once('value').then((userDoc) => {

      const senderName = userDoc.firstName //get('firstName')

      const notificationBody = (imageUrl === "") ? "You received a new image message." : messageTxt

        //build media messages notification
        const payload = {
            notification: {
              title: senderName + " sent you a message",
              body: messageTxt
            },
            data: {
              SENDER_NAME: senderName,
              SENDER_ID: fromId

            }//end data
        }//end payload

        //send message
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload).then( response => {
          const stillRegisteredTokens = registrationTokens

          response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
                    const error = result.error
                    if (error) {
                        const failedRegistrationToken = registrationTokens[index]
                        console.error('blah', failedRegistrationToken, error)
                        if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token'
                            || error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                                const failedIndex = stillRegisteredTokens.indexOf(failedRegistrationToken)
                                if (failedIndex > -1) {
                                    stillRegisteredTokens.splice(failedIndex, 1)
                                }
                            }
                    }
                })//end forEach

                return admin.database().ref("fcmtokens/" + recipientId).update({
                    registrationTokens: stillRegisteredTokens
                })//end update

        })//end sendToDevice


    })//end return-then

  })//end return-then

});
```

This is my `fcmtokens` database structure node:

```
"fcmtokens" : {
    "dBQdpR7l1WT2utKVxdX2" : {
      "registration-tokens" : {
        "c4PSCAUAg5s:Yw95DyVxwElE88LwX7" : true
      }
    }
  }
```

**Question update:**
The update database part of my function above is creating a separate branch called `registrationTokens` of all active tokens. I want to overwrite and update the current token under `registration-tokens` instead?

```
return admin.database().ref("fcmtokens/" + recipientId).update({
                        registrationTokens: stillRegisteredTokens
                    })//end update
```

Image showing the new `registrationTokens` branch being created.

[image]

Comment: What does the data under `registration-tokens` look like?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it is a `String : Bool` structure such as `tokenStringValue: true`

Comment: Instead of describing it, add a snippet of the actual JSON to your question please. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). In general try to reproduce the problem without any external dependencies. So can you hardcode the values of `toId` and other parameters and still have the same problem? If so, do this and update the code in the question. It'll make it much easier for us to see what's going on.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, I have updated my question to include a snippet of my datastrcuture (sorry I didn't know you could export it as a JSON, I'm new to all of this). Also, I have hard-coded all the dependencies as suggested and the function works (it triggers a notification message). My issue is that I am struggling in reading the database to get the values required.

Comment: Cool. If hardcoded values work, the problem has nothing to do with the call to FCM, and is likely just in loading from the database. This type of problem isolation is key to troubleshooting. You could do the same for Cloud Functions. If you have the same problem in a local Node.js script, the problem is unrelated to Cloud Functions. Those two steps can cut your problem area into 1/3, and make it significantly easier to help. For more hints, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data structure, this code:

```
admin.database().ref('/fcmtokens/' + toId + '/registration-tokens').once('value').then((userTok) => {
  const registrationTokens = userTok.val()
```

Leads to `registrationTokens` being:

```
{
  "c4PSCAUAg5s:Yw95DyVxwElE88LwX7" : true
}
```

You then call `sendToDevice` with:

```
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload).then( response => {
```

But if you look at the [reference documentation for `sendToDevice](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendToDevice), it says:

> **registrationTokens**
>
> Array of string
>
> An array of registration tokens for the devices to which to send the message.

And clearly your `registrationTokens` is not an array, but just an object.

To convert it to an array use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
  const registrationTokens = Object.keys(userTok.val())
```

Comment: This worked - thanks for your feedback...I do have a small issue though, the function is updating the database with all active token under a separate branch called `/registrationTokens` and I thought it would be overwriting the ones under `/registration-tokens` - what am I missing here?

Comment: Check the spelling in your code: `update({
                    registrationTokens: stillRegisteredTokens
                })`. Since you tell the database to update `registrationTokens`, that's what it does. To update the correct node, you'll need to use `[]` notation: `var updates = {}; updates['registration-tokens'] = stillRegisteredTokens; ....update(updates);`

Comment: Note that this is a separate problem, so should've been posted as a new question. It now creates more confusion than necessary in both your original question, and in this comment chain.