# Push notification on Firebase Functions - Iterate onWrite returns

Tags: firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

So I am trying to send push notifications to user with using Firebase Functions & FCM. I referred to the sample code to populate my pushes and when I use the hardcoded token, it works and the push gets sent correctly. Below is my working cloud function code.

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
exports.sendChatNotification = functions.database.ref('/user_pushes/{uid}').onWrite((change, context) => {

const afterData = change.after.val();
//let tokens = "My_hardcoded_device_token"
console.log('tokens',afterData.fcm_tokens)
let tokens = afterData.fcm_tokens

const payload = {
notification: {
title: afterData.sender_name,
body: afterData.message,
sound: "default"
}
};
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
});
```

And below is my json of RTDB of '/user_pushes/{uid}'.

```
{ fcm_tokens: 
  { 'token1': 0, 
    'token2': 0, 
    'token3': 0, }, 
  message: '', 
  sender_name: 'sender name'
 }
```

Of course I want to get tokens from my database. I expected to use like for in loop to get my tokens from the node named 'fcm_tokens' but no luck yet to find proper snippet. I want my tokens to be in a kind of an array form so that the pushes can be sent to multiple receivers. I am an inexperienced self taught iOS developer and not yet learnt server side programming so if my approach to get this is not appropriate please do advise! Many thanks in advance!

###EDIT###

I tried to retrieve the tokens with below a line of code and it throws an another error saying that the token should not be empty string or an array although it is likely not empty. Maybe my token(s) are keys not the values and it is the reason why? If it is the case can anybody advise how to get the keys into an array?

```
let tokens = afterData.fcm_tokens
console.log('tokens',afterData.fcm_tokens)
```

```
tokens { 'fWgm79ifOUVSofW2XXhoKt:APA91bHovn04k5lwnkzfQD74VmekV8FoTSUh8pyr9d_I0EMDPuzFdKpD7Y4OU_AKHVjalGQaGE_I6A5m6livf8QrxHTSTmn9h6EB9qyBde_reQRcjU6cZLHLLXx2cO0w6f3MOZOFnYDv': 0 }
```

```
Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:254:16)
    at Messaging.validateRegistrationTokensType (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:729:19)
    at Messaging.sendToDevice (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:328:14)
    at exports.sendChatNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/srv/index.js:27:26)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:134:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it work after a few of workarounds. It turns out that it is quite simple. Just catch keys with forEach syntax to iterate through the json.

```
const tokens = Object.keys(afterData.fcm_tokens)
```

For more detail, please see below.

[Error with registration token in FCM with Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607152/error-with-registration-token-in-fcm-with-cloud-functions)

Comment: If you need values not keys then `const tokens = Object.values(afterData.fcm_tokens)`  will do the job.